# Using MultipeerConnectivity Framework with WiFly model?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

Is it possible to use [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity) Framework to establish a local communication between an iOS device and a [WiFly](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/wireless-connectivity/human-interface/rn-software/wifly)? In other words, is the framework is strictly used between iOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say that it´s strictly used for iOS devices only for the `MultipeerConnectivity`. If you´re interested in Android - iOS, you have to check for another framework, make sure though that it´s approved by Apples [App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).